# How do I generate inner static class to access parent class's private constructor?

Tags: java, class, static, generator, private

Anyone know anything about class generation?

I'd like to generate inner static class to access parent class's private constructor.

Using generated code is many times faster than reflection, since JIT only optimizes reflection after some amount of time (cold start takes still long time) and apparently I'd need synthetic classes etc for that stuff, maybe somebody have some knowledge over it?

Answer (score -1):

An inner class can always access private fields and methods of the parent class.

```
class A {
    private A() {
        System.out.println("private constructor called");
    }

    static class Inner {
        Inner () {
            System.out.println("constructor of static inner class called");
            new A();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A.Inner();
    }
}
```

Comment: generated one i mean, 
heard of ASM?
point is that original class doesn't have that inner class
so i try to generate one at runtime
using ASM bytecode generator.
in theory it should work.

Comment: since as you can see inner classes can access parents

Comment: Did you try it out? And by the way, what is the problem with a "normal" class? Why does it have to be generated *at runtime*?

Comment: As i said in the thread: Using generated code is many times faster than reflection, since JIT only optimizes reflection after some amount of time (cold start takes still long time) ....

Comment: I didn't tried it out ... i'm looking for some one who can help me with sharing his  knowledge. hmmm in theory it should work but i don't know how's it go in  reality.